# Getting inflatorException in Nexus 4

Tags: android

I am using viewPager for tabs. When I run my app in Nexus 7 it works fine but when I run it in Nexus 4 it returns the following error

`inflator exception`

I am quite new to Android development and I can't see where I have gone wrong. My code is below

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
```

Thank you

Comment: Post the detailed exception log

Comment: Can u post error log

Comment: check this line I just cast view. View layoutView =  (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

Comment: edited post for clarity and correctly formatted the code section